# How can I copy parts of a text file and paste them in a new one

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file containing HTML code of different websites like this one textfile:
[image: textfile] and I want to copy the source code one at a time and put them in a different text file because I want to compare it with another text file containing the same source code in order to find out if the website has been updated. Each time I copy the next source code to the new file the old one will be deleted so basically then new textfile must contain only one source code at a time.

I have been able to copy the source code of the first page only but I don't know how to read the file from where I left off in order to copy the next source code.

```
input="./Desktop/sourcecode0.txt"
while read -r var
do
    if [ "$var" != "</html>" ]
    then
        echo "$var" >> "./Desktop/htmlcode.txt"
        continue
    elif [ "$var" == "</html>" ]
    then

        echo "$var" >> "./Desktop/htmlcode.txt"
        break
    fi  
done < "$input"
```

Comment: Posting the example 'sourcecode0.txt' file as an image makes it much less useful.  See [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/4154375).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use rather sed  (stream editor) for this, above You can do with:

```
sed '/<\/html>/q' sample.html

sed '/<\/html>/q' input.html >> htmlcode.txt
```

What above does sed by it default print all lines and on regexp `<\/html>` is does `q` print that line and quit.

Could You provide example what You exactly need "to copy next sourcecode"

Comment: I mean that every time i want to grab the next html block from the sourcecode0.txt for example in the textfile i gave the first time i need to copy the html code that makes the test page 1 ,then the second time i want to grab the code for the test page 2 and so goes on until the last html page.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to split `sourcecode0.txt` into some file, and each file will contain one `<html></html>` block.

for this task you can use

```
split -p '<html>' ~/Desktop/test.txt htmlcode_
```

that will create files with names `htmlcode_aa, htmlcode_ab, htmlcode_ac...` the number of files is depend on the number of `<html></html>` block.

if you want you can add later `.txt` to each file by calling

```
find ~/Desktop/htmlcode_a* | xargs -I '{}' mv {} {}.txt
```